# Self left join in RavenDB

Tags: c#, linq, nosql, ravendb

In **RavenDB** I have a collection of web PageTextElement for different 10 or more languages. A translator should be able to see *a base language* like English and *compare it to another language* like eg Swedish so he easily can update a text or insert a translation if it is missing. To me it sounded like *a simple self left join*. I have now understood that RavenDB does not [support join out of the box. You have to use a map reduce index](http://ayende.com/blog/89089/ravendb-multi-maps-reduce-indexes). I think I that almost got it to work.

### I can express a self left join and a group by in RavenDB:

```sql
SELECT bt.Page,bt.Token,bt.Webtext AS baseText,COUNT(ct.Webtext) 
FROM dbo.PageTextElement_TB bt
LEFT JOIN dbo.PageTextElement_TB AS ct 
    ON bt.Page=ct.Page 
    AND bt.Token = ct.Token 
    AND ct.Language='sv' 
WHERE bt.Language='en'
GROUP BY bt.Page,bt.Token,bt.Webtext
```

### Result of what I can do

```
|Page       |Token              |baseText                                       |count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|home       |PriceModel         |Based on weight and oxygen consumption         |1
|home       |RebateModel        |Truly Unique talent can reduce price with 50%  |0
|home       |RulesOfBoarding    |Do not break line                              |1  
|home       |Welcome            |Welcome to Aniara                              |1
```

### But I want to express fields from both joined collections  in RavenDB:

```sql
SELECT bt.Page,bt.Token,bt.Webtext AS baseText,ct.Webtext AS compareText 
FROM dbo.PageTextElement_TB bt
LEFT JOIN dbo.PageTextElement_TB AS ct 
    ON bt.Page=ct.Page 
    AND bt.Token = ct.Token 
    AND ct.Language='sv' 
WHERE bt.Language='en'
```

### The Result I want Table

```
|Page       |Token              |baseText                         |compareText
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|home       |PriceModel         |Based on weight and oxygen consumption |Priset baseras på vikt och syreförbrukning
|home       |RebateModel        |Truly Unique talent can reduce price with 50%  |NULL
|home       |RulesOfBoarding    |Do not break line     |Träng dig ej i kön
|home       |Welcome            |Welcome to Aniara     |Välkommen till Aniara
```

### This is my map reduce index that almost does what I want.

```
 public class LeftJoinPageTextTranslationsCount : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<ComparePageTextElementCount>
        {
            public LeftJoinPageTextTranslationsCount()
            {
                AddMap<PageTextElement>(baseElements => 
                    from baseElement in baseElements.Where(l => l.Language == "en")
                    select new { Page = baseElement.Page, Token = baseElement.Token, baseElement.Webtext,WebtextCompare=(string)null, Count = 0 });

                AddMap<PageTextElement>(compareElements => 
                    from compareElement in compareElements.Where(l => l.Language == "sv")
                    select new { Page = compareElement.Page, Token = compareElement.Token, Webtext = (string)null,WebtextCompare=compareElement.Webtext, Count = 1 }
                    );
                Reduce = results => from result in results
                                    group result by
                                        new{Page = result.Page,Token = result.Token}
                                        into g
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Page = g.Select(x => x.Page).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                                            Token = g.Select(x => x.Token).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                                            Webtext = g.Select(x => x.Webtext).Where(x => x != null).First(),
                                            WebtextCompare=g.Select(x => x.Webtext).Where(x => x != null).Last(),
                                            Count = g.Sum( x => x.Count)
                                        };
                Index(x => x.Webtext, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
            }
        }
```

### Result from map reduce index

```javascript
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "PriceModel",
  "Webtext": "Based on weight and oxygen consumption",
  "WebtextCompare": "Based on weight and oxygen consumption",
  "Count": "1"
}
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "RebateModel",
  "Webtext": "Truly Unique talent can reduce price with 50% ",
  "WebtextCompare": "Truly Unique talent can reduce price with 50% ",
  "Count": "0"
}
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "Welcome",
  "Webtext": "Welcome to Aniara",
  "WebtextCompare": "Welcome to Aniara",
  "Count": "1"
}
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "RulesOfBoarding",
  "Webtext": "Do not break line",
  "WebtextCompare": "Do not break line",
  "Count": "1"
}
```

### My question is

**Why does the english text appear where the swedish text should be?**

Unfortunately *the WebtextCompare field shows the English text instead of the Swedish*.
More abundant code can be found at my [gist](https://gist.github.com/patriklindstrom/6651718): 
or my [LeftJoin experiment project at github](https://github.com/patriklindstrom/LeftJoinRavenDB/tree/StackOverFlowQuestion): Actually the Count in my map reduce index above is not necessary it is the WebTextCompare field that I want to have the other language (swedish in this example).

### Result from map reduce index that I want

```javascript
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "PriceModel",
  "Webtext": "Based on weight and oxygen consumption",
  "WebtextCompare": "Priset baseras på vikt och syreförbrukning",
  "Count": "1"
}
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "RebateModel",
  "Webtext": "Truly Unique talent can reduce price with 50% ",
  "WebtextCompare": NULL,
  "Count": "0"
}
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "Welcome",
  "Webtext": "Welcome to Aniara",
  "WebtextCompare": "Välkommen till Aniara",
  "Count": "1"
}
{
  "Page": "home",
  "Token": "RulesOfBoarding",
  "Webtext": "Do not break line",
  "WebtextCompare": "Träng dig ej i kön",
  "Count": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there appears to be a few things going on here.

a) The reason you had so much trouble is here:

```
Webtext = g.Select(x => x.Webtext).Where(x => x != null).First(),
WebtextCompare=g.Select(x => x.Webtext).Where(x => x != null).Last(),
```

Note the second line, you have *Webtext* there. Instead of WebtextCompare.

Also, you shouldn't use First or Last in indexes, you should use FirstOrDefault or LastOrDefault.

Here is the full index definition that you want:

```
public class LeftJoinPageTextTranslationsCount : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<ComparePageTextElementCount>
{
    public LeftJoinPageTextTranslationsCount()
    {
        AddMap<PageTextElement>(baseElements =>
                                from baseElement in baseElements.Where(l => l.Language == "en")
                                select
                                    new
                                        {
                                            baseElement.Page,
                                            baseElement.Token,
                                            baseElement.Webtext,
                                            WebtextCompare = (string) null,
                                            Count = 0
                                        });

        AddMap<PageTextElement>(compareElements =>
                                from compareElement in compareElements.Where(l => l.Language == "sv")
                                select
                                    new
                                        {
                                            compareElement.Page,
                                            compareElement.Token,
                                            Webtext = (string) null,
                                            WebtextCompare = compareElement.Webtext,
                                            Count = 1
                                        }
            );
        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by
                                new { result.Page, result.Token }
                                into g
                                select new
                                    {
                                        g.Key.Page,
                                        g.Key.Token,
                                        Webtext = g.Select(x => x.Webtext).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                        WebtextCompare = g.Select(x => x.WebtextCompare).FirstOrDefault(x => x != null),
                                        Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
                                    };
        Index(x => x.Webtext, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

[image: Proper results]

B) LeftJoinProject can be handled using the following index:

```
public class LeftJoinIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<LeftJoinIndex.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string TeacherName;
        public string[] Students;
    }
    public LeftJoinIndex()
    {
        AddMap<Students>(studentsList =>
                        from list in studentsList
                        from student in list.List
                        select new
                            {
                                TeacherName = student.HomeRoomTeacher,
                                Students = new[] { student.Name }
                            }
            );

        AddMap<Teachers>(teacherLists =>
                        from list in teacherLists
                        from teacher in list.List
                        select new
                            {
                                TeacherName = teacher.Name,
                                Students = new string[0]
                            }
        );

        Reduce = results =>
                 from reduceResult in results
                 group reduceResult by reduceResult.TeacherName
                     into g
                     select new
                         {
                             TeacherName = g.Key,
                             Students = g.SelectMany(x => x.Students)
                         };
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

[image: LeftJoinIndex output]

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. But do I need to create one map/reduce index for  every combination of languages? One index for en-sv one for en-it, en-jp and if I want all combo also sv-it, it-jp etc . If it is so Is there a way to create index classes programatically. Check all permutations of language combos at start up and create one index for every combination. Or can I express the language as parameter? For this project I only have 10 languages so I can make it fixed. But I just wanted to see what is possibly.